# karate-summary report does not contain details when upgraded to 1.4.1

Tags: karate

the karate summary report does not contain details when upgraded to 1.4.1

Like if I have a print statement, that detail was available in 1.4.0. but I can't find this in 1.4.1. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue that happens only when you mix multiple other libraries leading to dependency conflicts. Solutions and workarounds are given in this ticket: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2436